# ListView - Each item having an ID?

Tags: android

Hey, I was curious if there was a way that I can assign each menu item in a `ListView`  its ID from the SQLite database, so that when I do something like onClick, or using a ContextMenu, I can tell what item / row I am referencing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep when you implement the onItemClickListener the id argument is what you are wanting.